# Can bash write a command to the terminal input?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a long winded command. I created a bash function to make it easier to remember.

For example:

```sh
phew() {
   echo 'This is not really my super long winded command'
}
```

This is all great. However, I don't want to execute the command yet. I just want `phew` to do all the typing for me.

**Is there a way to write a string of text to the terminal input?**

Adapting the example above:

```sh
phew() {
  foo "echo 'This is not really my super long winded command'"
}

$ phew # would write the next line for me
$ echo 'This is not really my super long winded command' # Then, I press enter. Producing...

# This is not really my super long winded command
```

Comment: No, it can't feed into terminal input. Maybe you can do what you want with a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Take a look at the `readline` customization features in bash.

Answer (score 2):

Try one of these:

1. `bash` required:

   ```
   phew() {
     printf '%s' "Type something: "
     read c < <(echo $@)
     echo $c
   }
   ```

   (Delete the second `echo` to just run the input string.)  Test:

   ```
   phew Tro lo lo lo LO
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   Type something: Tro lo lo lo LO
   ```
2. Plain old Bourne shell:

   ```
   phew() {
       c="echo 'This is not really my super long winded command'"
       read -p "Hit enter to run: $c"
       $c
   }
   ```

   Test:

   ```
   phew
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   Hit enter to run: echo 'This is not really my super long winded command'
   ```

   ...user hits *Enter*.  Output:

   ```
   'This is not really my super long winded command'
   ```

   ---

   This can be more dangerously generalized to:

   ```
   phew() {
       c="$@"
       read -p "Hit enter to run: $c"
       $c
   }
   ```

   Where the user would type `phew "echo 'yadda yadda'"`.  It's safer
   to only use a function like that in a script to save the programmer
   the bother of writing different versions of `phew`.

Comment: This is likely what i'll end up going with. Ideally, I would like to edit the command on the fly. Tack on a few extra flags and such.

Comment: This should effectively do what you want: `cmd="cmd goes here" ; read -ei "$cmd" ; $REPLY`

Comment: @TNierath, Thanks... that works, and got me experimenting with the `bash` shell's `read` command.  See revised answer.

Comment: actually, `eval $REPLY` at the end would be better even. I think I'd prefer the alias expand option for most use-cases, but it's nevertheless good to know

Answer (score 2):

You can create an alias, then use `M-C-e` (Ctrl+Alt+e on PC keyboards) to expand it.

```
alias phew="echo 'This is a very long command'"
```

after which typing `phew` followed by `M-C-e` will leave `echo 'This is a very long command'` on the command line.

Caution: `M-C-e` will expand **everything** on the command line, including command substitution (backticks) which will cause the enclosed command to be executed.  Make sure that is what you want.  There is a separate readline function to only expand aliases; by default it isn't bound to a key, but you could bind it to one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, but it's not really what I am looking for. It's far too specific on the environment.

### Requires AppleScript and iTerm2.

Therefore, it only works on a mac.

```
write_noline() {
  osascript \
  -e "tell application \"iTerm2\" to tell current window to tell current session to write text \"${@}\" newline NO"
}
```

Using the example:

```
phew() {
  write_noline "echo 'This is not really my super long winded command'"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe put the rest of your text as a argument

script:

```
ls "$1"
```

command line:

```
>script '/home/me/Pictures'
```